# Confusing behavior of mongoose on populations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using nested population of different fields of a collection , there are chained 5 populations , sometimes it returns one of the fields populated, sometimes it returns all them without population .

how can we populate all the fields ?

[image]

these are examples of my populations .

Comment: Hi, could you add the shema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.populate({
    path: 'cases',
    populate: {
        path: 'case',
        populate: [
            {
                path: 'patient'
            },
            {
                path: 'createdBy'
            }
        ],
    }
})
```